# PLS-00103 Encountered the symbol DECLARE when expecting

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to write UDF in oracle the returns some based on the difference between a supplied date and today. Below is my code, and error

```
Error(5,5): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DECLARE" when expecting one of the following:     begin function pragma procedure subtype type <an identifier>    <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> current cursor delete    exists prior The symbol "begin" was substituted for "DECLARE" to continue. 




CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FN_AGE_RANGE(
        SAP_DATE IN VARCHAR2 )
      RETURN VARCHAR2
    IS
      ResultVar VARCHAR2;
      -- Declare additional variables here
      DECLARE
        TheDate DATE;
        TheDiff NUMBER;
      BEGIN
        --convert to date
        SELECT
          CASE
            WHEN SAPDate = '00.00.0000'
            THEN NULL
            ELSE to_date(SAP_DATE,'dd.mm.yyyy')
          END
        INTO TheDate
        FROM DUAL;
        --workout date difference
        SELECT DATEDIFF(d,GETDATE() , TheDate)
        INTO TheDiff
        FROM DUAL;
        --set the frequency
        SELECT
          CASE
            WHEN TheDiff < -180
            THEN '>6 Months'
            WHEN TheDiff < -90
            THEN '3-6 Months'
            WHEN TheDiff < 0
            THEN '<3 Months'
          END
        INTO ResultVar
        FROM DUAL;
        RETURN(ResultVar);
      END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/LNPLS/CREATE-PROCEDURE-statement.htm#LNPLS01373
The decare section does not start with the keyword `DECLARE`. Remove it!

Comment: Thanks, spotted a bunch of other errors, but that got rid of the one in this topic